# how to integrate graphs and pie charts in Google sites as a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to integrate pie chart and graphs in google sites can anyone please help me out with google apps script

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/index.html) ?

Comment: ^updated the link - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/index.html